# Using functors for global variables?

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm learning Haskell, and am implementing an algorithm for a class. It works fine, but a requirement of the class is that I keep a count of the total number of times I multiply or add two numbers. This is what I would use a global variable for in other languages, and my understanding is that it's anathema to Haskell.

One option is to just have each function return this data along with its actual result. But that doesn't seem fun.

Here's what I was thinking: suppose I have some function `f :: Double -> Double`. Could I create a data type `(Double, IO)` then use a functor to define multiplication across a `(Double, IO)` to do the multiplication and write something to IO. Then I could pass my new data into my functions just fine.

Does this make any sense? Is there an easier way to do this?

EDIT: To be more clear, in an OO language I would declare a class which inherits from `Double` and then override the `*` operation. This would allow me to not have to rewrite the type signature of my functions. I'm wondering if there's some way to do this in Haskell.

Specifically, if I define `f :: Double -> Double` then I should be able to make a `functor :: (Double -> Double) -> (DoubleM -> DoubleM)` right? Then I can keep my functions the same as they are now.

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to read about monads after having thought about this problem. This is the kinds of problems they aim to solve, and I think you almost got it right.

Comment: Notice the `Writer` monad suggestions are basically an enhanced version of what you already said. "One option is to just have each function return this data along with its actual result". Except, with monads, it *is* fun! xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of using `Writer` for this purpose:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Applicative -- only for the <$> spelling of fmap

type OpCountM = Writer (Sum Int)

add :: (Num a) => a -> a -> OpCountM a
add x y = tell (Sum 1) >> return (x+y)

mul :: (Num a) => a -> a -> OpCountM a
mul x y = tell (Sum 1) >> return (x*y)

-- and a computation
fib :: Int -> OpCountM Int
fib 0 = return 0
fib 1 = return 1
fib n = do
    n1 <- add n (-1)
    n2 <- add n (-2)
    fibn1 <- fib n1
    fibn2 <- fib n2
    add fibn1 fibn2

main = print (result, opcount)
  where
  (result, opcount) = runWriter (fib 10)
```

That definition of fib is pretty long and ugly... monadifying can be a pain.  It can be made more concise with applicative notation:

```
fib 0 = return 0
fib 1 = return 1
fib n = join (fib <$> add n (-1) <*> add n (-2))
```

But admittedly more opaque for a beginner.  I wouldn't recommend that way until you are pretty comfortable with the idioms of Haskell.

Comment: Oh, I bundled both counts into one.  If you want to count separately, combine this answer with @mokus's.

Comment: He didn't actually state that he wanted them separately, that was just my first inclination and I ran with it.

Comment: I would have to modify the type signature here though, right? There's no way to make `fib` think it's taking in a `Double` but really it's taking in an `OpCountM Double`?

Comment: @Xodarap, yeah, my second fib has the same sig as the first one.  There's no way to trick it, though you can make fib parametric: `fib :: (Num a) => a -> a` and then pass it one of the magic `Num` instances that @chrisdb and @mokus suggest.  Those solutions can be subtle, though.  Say you define `f x = x + x` and `g x = f (x + x)`.  `g` will be recorded as performing *3* additions rather than the 2 that would really occur.  That's why I suggest using a monad instead of a magic `Num` instance, because you have control over what it means to do a subcomputation.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, your first idea (return the counts with each value) is not a bad one, and can be expressed more abstractly by the Writer monad (in `Control.Monad.Writer` from the mtl package or `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer` from the transformers package).  Essentially, the writer monad allows each computation to have an associated "output", which can be anything as long as it's an instance of `Monoid` - a class which defines:

- The empty output (`mempty`), which is the output assigned to 'return'
- An associative function (`mappend') that combines outputs, which is used when sequencing operations

In this case, your output is a count of operations, the 'empty' value is zero, and the combining operation is addition.  For example, if you're tracking operations separately:

```
data Counts = Counts { additions: Int, multiplications: Int }
```

Make that type an instance of `Monoid` (which is in the module `Data.Monoid`), and define your operations as something like:

```
add :: Num a => a -> a -> Writer Counts a
add x y = do
    tell (Counts {additions = 1, multiplications = 0})
    return (x + y)
```

The writer monad, together with your Monoid instance, then takes care of propagating all the 'tells' to the top level.  If you wanted, you could even implement a `Num` instance for `Num a => Writer Counts a` (or, preferably, for a newtype so you're not creating an orphan instance), so that you can just use the normal numerical operators.

Comment: Thanks! Can you take a look at my edit? I think this will work well, but I'm wondering if there's a more clever way (since I'm really doing this to learn Haskell rather than have a clear/efficient solution).

Comment: @Xodarap: If your functions are more general, you can get what you're looking for by creating a Num instance as I mentioned.  For example, if `f:: Num a => a -> a`, then `f` will work for `Double` or for `Writer Counts Double`, assuming such an instance is available.  Beware, though, that in doing this you end up counting things in odd ways, as @chrisdb described in a comment on his answer.  In fact, I realize that the code I have given here suffers exactly the same problem, and @luqui's below does not.  I'll edit mine, and hopefully if you look at the edit you'll see the problem.

Comment: Wow, look at the comments.  We are thinking in three point surround sound.

Answer (score 1):

What level of Haskell are you learning?  There are probably two reasonable answers: have each function return its counts along with its return value like you suggested, or (more advanced) use a monad such as `State` to keep the counts in the background.  You could also write a special-purpose monad to keep the counts; I do not know if that is what your professor intended.  Using `IO` for mutable variables is not the elegant way to solve the problem, and is not necessary for what you need.

Comment: The class isn't about Haskell; we can use whatever language we want, and this is what I chose. I'm just getting to the part in "Learn you a haskell for great good" about monads - do you think using `State` will be above my head?

Comment: Not `State` though!  This is a perfect use case for `Writer`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, apart from returning a tuple or using the state monad explicitly, might be to wrap it up in a data type. Something like:

```
data OperationCountNum = OperationCountNum Int Double deriving (Show,Eq)

instance Num OperationCountNum where
    ...insert appropriate definitions here
```

The class Num defines functions on numbers, so you can define the functions +, * etc on your OperationCountNum type in such a way that they keep track of the number of operations required to produce each number.

That way, counting the operations would be hidden and you can use the normal +, * etc operations. You just need to wrap your numbers up in the OperationCountNum type at the start and then extract them at the end.

In the real world, this probably isn't how you'd do it, but it has the advantage of making the code easier to read (no explicit detupling and tupling) and being fairly easy to understand.

Comment: This is assuming you don't like the State monad solution, which IMO is probably the most normal way to do it.

Comment: I've also been thinking, and my proposal above only works if the algorithm you are implementing does not contain any common sub-expression sharing. For example, `x = 1 + 2; y = x + 1; z = x + 2;` contains 3 addition operations, but if you ignore the fact that x is shared you might incorrectly calculate that there are 4: `y = (1 + 2) + 1; z = (1 + 2) + 2;`